# Scroll horizontally on a webpage using Javascript Executor for a Selenium script

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I want to scroll my web page horizonally to the other end using Javascript Executor for my Selenium script. Can anyone help me with the snippet that could directly move the scrollbar horizontally to the other end.

Note : I have already tried the below concept of scrolling the page till a particular element becomes visible. I am looking for something more direct.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -

js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = *number of pixels*(e.g. 50);", Element);

`js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = 50;", Element);`

This will scroll the element over by 50 pixels.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: Let me give a try to this.

Comment: @edotcarter pls add some description to your answer what it does and what not and format it thanks